# android Button background get Stretched while LinearLayout not

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using a image for the background of the button.

Like this .

```
   <Button
        android:id="@+id/invitefrnd_mail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/mailreport_button" />
```

The background drawable image get stretched when i see it in mobile, while if i use LinearLayout instead of button the image do not streach

like this

```
   <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/invitefrnd_mail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/mailreport_button" />
```

Can any one explain the reason for this ?

Complete layout with LinearLayout.... for buttons replace LinearLayout with buttons

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttons_top_invite"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/invitefrnd_contacts"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/contactsinvite_button" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/invitefrnd_facebook"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/facebookinvite_button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Why you are setting     android:layout_weight="1" ?

Comment: Remove android:layout_weight="1" from Button

Comment: android:layout_weight="1" looks strange if not wrong. Could you please post your complete layout? Thanks.

Comment: I kept two buttons in a linearlayout where weightsum is 2 and thats why for each weight is 1

Comment: Paste your entire xml file.

Comment: @Hardy Question updated

Comment: Do not use `android:layout_weight="1"` in the Button and though its not working on Button you can use a `LinearLayout` and give a `OnClickListener` to it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can even use Linearlayout if it working fine. Make onclick listener to your linearlayout.

```
<LinearLayout     
    android:id="@+id/buttons_top_invite"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"   onClick="firstButton"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/invitefrnd_contacts"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"  onClick="secondbutton"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/contactsinvite_button" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/invitefrnd_facebook"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/facebookinvite_button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

In your Java Code :

```
public void firstbutton(View v) {
        //your first button 
    }

    public void secondbutton(View v){
        //your second button 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks buddy i know it is working fine my question is why this is happening . Using button why the image is stretching .

Comment: @SureshBora If you provide weight in both buttons, entire width of the layout divided into two parts. and each button will get space. SO if your image width is less that width which button occupies it will stretch.